# Downloading to a selected directory in android DownloadManager

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I'm trying to let user select download destination folder by PICK_FOLDER and use the selected folder in android DownloadManager. The problem is DownloadManager.Request, accepts only file uri, this is while pick folder returns tree uri which can not be used. How should I get the file uri of the download file in the tree selected by user?

Comment: I do not know PICK_FOLDER. Where do you see that?

Comment: Please give an example of a content scheme of the picked folder.